# SQL Troubleshooting Help on Table Structure

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to calculate average number of days between a customer's 1st and 3rd purchase, but struggling to get the data ordered in a way that will allow me to calculate.

I currently have the below data table. (Note: Order sequence number refers to the number order for that customer.)

| Order Date | Customer Number | Order Sequence Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-20 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-20 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-21 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020-10-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-08-06 | 3 | 1 |
| 2020-09-06 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020-09-09 | 3 | 3 |

I've been trying to get the data to look like the following table. [To then be able to calculate datediff on the last two columns.]

| Customer Number | Order Count | First Order Date | Third Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-09-20 | 2021-01-21 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-10-01 | Null |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-08-06 | 2020-09-09 |

I've completely messed up the code, but here's what I've been trying.

```
    CREATE TABLE X2 as
    SELECT
        customer_number,
        max(order_sequence_number) as order_count,
      CASE
        WHEN order_sequence_number = 1 then order_date
        ELSE null
      END as first_order_date,
      CASE
        WHEN order_sequence_number = 3 then order_date
        ELSE null
      END as third_order_date
    FROM X1
    GROUP BY customer_number;
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY, should raise an exception.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but you need aggregation functions:

```
SELECT customer_number,
       max(order_sequence_number) as order_count,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_sequence_number = 1 THEN order_date END) as first_order_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_sequence_number = 3 THEN order_date END) as third_order_date
FROM X1
GROUP BY customer_number;
```

To get the difference in days, you would just subtract the two expressions using whatever date arithmetic is supported in your database.